# Hatcher Theorem 1.7 Detail

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

In his proof of Theorem 1.7, Hatcher uses the following covering space of $S^1$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be given by $f(x)=(\cos2\pi x,\sin2\pi x,x)$. We then take the range $f[\mathbb{R}]$ of $f$, with the projection $p:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$. Hatcher takes a loop $l$ with basepoint $(1,0)$ in $S^1$ and lifts it to a path $\tilde{l}$ in $f[\mathbb{R}]$ with endpoints $(1,0,0)$ and $(1,0,n)$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. The path $\tilde{\omega}_n$ given by $\tilde{\omega}_n(x)=(\cos2\pi nx,\sin2\pi nx,nx)$ has the same endpoints, so he takes the linear homotopy $h_t=t\tilde{l}+(1-t)\tilde{\omega}_n$ between them. He then claims that $ph_t$ is a homotopy between $l$ and $\omega_n$, defined to be $p\tilde{\omega}_n$.

My problem is this: wouldn’t $h_t$ generally leave the helix $f[\mathbb{R}]$, or more importantly, the cylinder $S^1\times\mathbb{R}$ containing it? Then for any $x$ such that $h_t(x)$ is not in the cylinder, we would have $ph_t(x)\not\in S^1$, so $ph_t$ is not a homotopy in $S^1$. Wouldn’t we need to make $h_t$ something like $f(tf^{-1}\tilde{l}+(1-t)f^{-1}\tilde{\omega}_n)$?

Comment: In the proof of Theorem 1.7, $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{\omega}_n$ are maps $I \to \mathbb{R}$, so linear interpolation makes sense.  The "helix in $\mathbb{R}^3$" is just for visualization purposes; it's not what actually is used in the proof.

Comment: Oh right thank you. That makes sense.

Comment: @JHF You should give an official answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here's an answer recapitulating my comment above so that this question is not left unanswered.

The part in question of the proof of Theorem 1.7 is to show that every loop $f: I \to S^1$ at the basepoint $x_0$ is homotopic to a "standard" loop $\omega_n: I \to S^1$ that winds around the circle counterclockwise $n$ times at a constant speed for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Using the theory of covering spaces, we show that $f: I \to S^1$ has a unique lift $\tilde{f}: I \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\tilde{f}(0) = 0$.  Moreover, we have $\tilde{f}(1) = n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  We want to show that $\tilde{f}$ is homotopic to the map $\tilde{\omega}_n: x \mapsto nx$; once we have this, composing with the projection $p: \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ gives a homotopy between $p \circ \tilde{f} = f$ and $p \circ \tilde{\omega}_n = \omega_n$.

Hatcher claims that linear interpolation between $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{\omega}_n$ works, using the linear structure of the codomain $\mathbb{R}$.  Of course, even though the helix described right after the statement of the theorem is topologically equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$, it is not convex in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so you are correct that if we tried to linearly interpolate in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the homotopy may "leave" the helix and is thus invalid.

Fortunately, this is not what Hatcher is proposing to do.  Instead, we linearly interpolate within $\mathbb{R}$ and not its embedding in $\mathbb{R}^3$; you can imagine this as sliding points *along* the helix between the endpoints of the homotopy at a uniform rate - so the homotopy never "leaves" the helix - if you want to visualize the covering projection $p: \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ literally as a projection in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Occasionally, it may help with geometric visualization and developing intuition to imagine $\tilde{f}: I \to \mathbb{R}$ as a path on a helix in 3D, but this is not needed for, and not used in, the actual proof.